# How can mysqli_real_escape_string fail to prevent a SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

First of all, I get that people want to use stored procedures so that they reuse queries and have the escaping taken care of. However, I have read many developers say that `mysqli_real_escape_string` can not 100% prevent SQL injections. Can someone please provide an example of this?

From my limited knowledge on the subject I would say that `mysqli_real_escape_string` would *always* be fine for strings but for numerical values you could be caught out unless you check the number is an int, float, double, etc.

EDIT: I forgot to add something critical: assume that the charset is UTF8 and mysqli_set_charset has been called accordingly. The only injecting I've seen rely a handful of charsets (none of which are UTF8).

Comment: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: The answer by the link is too flashy to my taste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you are using `mysqli_set_charset()` to set client encoding, and `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is used to format **strings only**, it is perfectly safe.

However, if your question implied using this function right in the application code, instead of behind-the-scenes processing of placeholder-based query or at least in the form of PDO's `quote()`-like function (which does escaping **and** quoting at once) it is straight way to injection.

It is not function itself being a problem, but the way it is used:

- as it does only *part* of required formatting, one can easily forget another part and slip into trouble
- or even it can be easily misused, to format not a string but another literal which will no benefit from escaping at all.
- second, when it's used right in the application code, it is usage become inconsistent or occasional, as there is no way to force a developer to format every literal properly and without fail. This again may lead to inaccuracy and injection.

That's why **you have to always use a placeholder** to represent data in the query (while mysqli_real_escape_string can be used to process this placeholder all right)

Comment: Additional caveat [required](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23277864) re `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` mode with double-quoted literals.