# Preparing an array of strings to add to database

Tags: php, database, escaping, addslashes

I have the following array to add to the database.

```
$arr = array("a'a","b'b","c'c");
```

To escape the single quotes before adding to database I use this for loop

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
  $arr[$i] = addslashes($arr[$i]);  
}
```

And it works just fine. But if the original array is changed to this:

```
$arr = array("first"=>"a'a","b'b","c'c");
```

then I get the following error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 150994944 bytes) in /home/filepath/file.php on line 12

I'm not sure why I get this error when the array has a custom key of "first". I wouldn't get this error if I manually use addslashes to each array value but whenever I put it in a for loop I get the error.

Does anyone have a work around for applying addslashes to each array value? I've tried mysqli_real_escape_string instead of addslashes but I got the same error.

Comment: use prepared statements for your inserts instead of adding and removing slashes

Comment: The way you are escaping is not safe , Use prepared statements and please let us see your addslashes function so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use a prepared statement with bound variables instead of manually escaping your values (with the wrong function...).

The reason of your error, is that you have generated a never-ending loop.

At first your array has 3 elements, but as you use a numeric `for` loop instead of a `foreach`, on the first two iterations you will escape your last 2 values, indices `0` and `1`. On the third iteration, you try to escape the element in your array with key `2` as `$i` is `2`.

But there is no element in your array that has key `2`. So you add a fourth element. And that happens every iteration after that; you add new elements and `$i` will never reach the count of your array, causing you to loop until memory runs out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You mentioned that I'm escaping my values with the wrong function. Can you tell me briefly what is the problem with using addslashes or  mysqli_real_escape_string? I took a short php course online and I was told to use mysqli_real_escape_string to ensure special characters do not cause problems.

Comment: @blah Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16315399/3783243 or the dup tagged there

Comment: @blah `mysqli_real_escape_string` would be better, but as you can see in the manual, there is still a big **if**. Better forget the escaping and simply use a prepared statement.